# Serializing the data entered in a UserControl to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, windows-forms-designer

I have a `UserControl` that I created at runtime from the main form class of the same project.

I need to send all the information (Location, name, tag, text ...) of that `UserControl` that I am creating dynamically in a JSON file. I'm using the JSON.NET library.

I was doing the following but it does not work:

```
UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
string outputJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UC);
File.WriteAllText("mifile.json", outputJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

The user control will contain some controls which contain the values you want to expose.

You could do this by creating a Data Transfer Object to serialize, and then populate this property with the data from the controls.

So create a DTO, in this example for a control that contains Person data:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And expose it from your user control through a method or property:

```
public PersonDto Data
{
    get
    {
        return new PersonDto
        {
            FirstName = this.FirstNameTextBox.Text,
            LastName = this.LastNameTextBox.Text,
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can serialize that property:

```
UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
// ...
string outputJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UC.Data);
```